# Dialog boxes and event handling in MFC

Tags: mfc

I have created a dialog box containing a textbox and a button. 
And when the button is pressed , a message box with the textbox content should appear.....but  it  is not getting displayed.

```
void dilg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    CString str;
    tx1.GetWindowText(str);
    MessageBox(str);
}
```

Comment: Check in you `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP` may be you have deleted line, something like this.
`ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, &dilg::OnBnClickedButton1)`

Comment: Have you set a break point in OnBnClickedButton?